# How to find Python objects that have multiple references at time of in-place modification

Tags: python

Is there any generic strategy (debug or code analysis) to find objects / class properties in a big python project that may get referenced multiple times and modified in-place?

Context:

In Python it is very easy to create multiple references to the same object - which can lead to really surprising things, if one isn't aware of this. While i know that this fact exists since my earliest Python trials, i actually didn't thought much of it. This was until i had a really nasty bug last week, that was induced by an in-place operation, that i put in my code some years ago, never realizing at this time, that it may leed to problems, if i reference that same object again later on (not remembering then that it may be in-place modified somewhere else...).

So assume a class like:

```
class A:
    _x = None
    n = 0
    def set_range(self,n):
        self.n = n
        self._x = list(range(n))

    def get_range(self):
        return self._x

    def get_range_extended(self,n):
        return self._x + list(range(self.n,self.n+n))
```

As long as you know and remember all the internals of this class, it is obvious that doing:

```
obj = A()
obj.set_range(10)

# old long forgotten code
a = obj.get_range()
a.reverse()

# new code
b = obj.get_range_extended(10)
```

will not only reverse the contents of `a` but also parts of `b` - because well - they are partially the same object (the list that was originally created by calling `set_range`).

So best practice to make sure that this won't happen, may be to create copies of properties in any class method before they are returned - right?

```
    def get_range(self):
        return self._x.copy()
```

OK this may solve the problem at its source. But often enough i can't do that, as the class is not in my scope. So i may be better of, to crawl through my code and find objects that may get referenced multiple times and check those for any in-place operations. Those places may justify an specific object copy... but how can i identify all those critical objects and places?

Comment: You're going to run into too many cases where the multiple references are benign. It's entirely normal to have multiple references to an object while you mutate it. For example, `for thing in stuff: modify(thing)` will typically have at least 3 references to each thing while it's being modified. One from `stuff`, one from the `thing` variable, and one owned by `modify`.

Comment: I'm sorry. This is sort of the reason why my mentors that were older and wiser than me told me to simply avoid mutator methods (outside of self-contained circumstances, e.g. building  list with .append and returning the value from some function). So always prefer `list(reversed(some_list))` over `some_list.reverse()`, or `sorted(some_list)` over `some_list.sort()`. I was also told to simply not expose mutator methods to my objects. This has been overall a good habit to build up.

Comment: @ user2357112: Sure thing, that's why i'm asking - reference count alone is not really helping. It would have to be filtered for some kind of code branches.

Comment: @ juanpa: ok so - you know of a "filter" to find all those mutator methods (for standard python objects anyway)?